# i found bitcoin wallet I need qr private key where i can get that code?

Tags: bitcoin-core

i found bitcoin wallet I need qr private key where i can get that code ? 
Is it impossible to get qr private code ?

Answer (score 1):

> **I need qr private key**

[QR codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) are a 2D barcode typically used by cryptocurrency wallets to present a payment-address which someone else uses to send you payment. They are also sometimes used when printing a private-key as a [paper wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Paper_wallet).

> **where i can get that code?**

Non-custodial wallets generally provide a means to extract the private-key. For example with Bitcoin-core you can use the CLI command [`dumpprivkey`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#dumpprivkey)

Most wallets are protected by a pass-phrase. If you don't know the pass-phrase, and can't guess it, you cannot extract the private-key.

---

If you believe the private-key was printed in QR-barcode form as a paper-wallet it will obviously be wherever the owner put it - we can't really help with that.

---

#### Found wallet

You have no access to the Bitcoins associated with a wallet if you don't have the wallet's passphrase and dont have the private-key and don't know where it is in printed form and don't know a seed-phrase used to generate the private keys.

---

#### Converting a private-key from text to QR-code

If you have full-access to the wallet you found and want to convert it to a paper wallet in QR-code form - you'll need the wallet to support that or export the private key in other form (e.g. [WIF](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format)) and then import it into software (perhaps a different wallet) that has the features you need.

For those comfortable with programming, I've seen people suggest downloading the HTML from, say, https://www.bitaddress.org and running that on a disconnected PC. It looks like client-side Javascript and can generate QR-codes from a known private-key with some modification. The Javascript libraries used appear to be open-source so can be obtained from the usual repositories.

Comment: People do sometimes use QR codes for private keys; e.g. this is a common way to have a paper wallet.

Comment: @Nate: Thanks, I'll delete that part of my answer

Answer (score 0):

The private key was originally used to generate the address.  So, you have to get the private key from whoever generated the address.  If you generated it, then hopefully it is stored in the software you used.

If you just found an address, or someone gave it to you, then you can't get the private key and cannot use the coins.